# asp.net C# variable as Image1.ImageUrl property

Tags: asp.net, variables

I would like to Click "buttonImage1" and have that store "photos/Image1.jpg"
into a var called Photo.  then have `ButtonImage2.ImageUrl = (Photo)`.

I am using an `UpdatePanel` to refresh the area with the images so the only problem is actually setting the variable correctly and then using it correctly.

Reworded: how can I store a path to an image in a variable then set it correctly as a image's URL path?

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Evt = ("~/events/ev2.jpg");
}   

protected void Image2_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Image1.ImageUrl = (Evt);    
}
```

Comment: what problem you are facing in this ?

Comment: @Buzz I updated my question to be more informative. Thank you!

Comment: make the variable `Evt` a public property

Comment: Thank you @user1512 i added protected static string Evt; and it works.
Thanks for your help as well Buzz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **`Server.MapPath`** to set image path

```
Image1.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath(Evt);
```

Comment: Thank you; I ended up globally defining my variable and using it as listed above but thanks!